# List.OrderByDescending Linq not working

Tags: c#, linq, list

Please have a look in the below code, I need an output in OrderedListDesc = {7,6,5,4,1,2,3,8,9} instead of {4,5,6,7,1,2,3,8,9}.

```
List<long> List = new List<long>() { 1,2,4,5,3,8,6,7,9 };
List<long> ListAsc = new List<long>() {  4,5,6,7 };
List<long> ListDesc = new List<long>() { 7,6,5,4 };
var OrderedListAsc = List.OrderBy(b => ListAsc.FindIndex(a => a == b)).ToList();
foreach (var l in OrderedListAsc)
{
    Console.Write(l+" ,");
}
Console.WriteLine();
var OrderedListDesc  = List.OrderByDescending(b => ListDesc.FindIndex(a => a == b)).ToList();
foreach (var l in OrderedListDesc)
{
    Console.Write(l + " ,");
}
```

Comment: It's not fully clear to me what you are trying to do. But do you realize that `ListDesc.FindIndex(a => a ==b))` returns `-1` for 1, 2, 3, 8 and 9? So this isn't very helpful in sorting...

Comment: you are right. Since it returns -1, it will arranged after all the elements in ListDesc. And I'm expecting that result in that order. But My requirement is to get the order of elements in ListDesc as 7,6,5,4 instead of 4,5,6,7 and followed by 1,2,3,8,9.

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple if you think about it:

The order of the elements found in `ListDesc`  should be the number itself, then you got your result:

```
var OrderedListDesc = List.OrderByDescending(b => ListDesc.Any(a => a == b) ? b : 0).ToList();
foreach (var l in OrderedListDesc)
{
    Console.Write(l + " ,");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what's happening, that is, why you're getting things in the wrong order, run this:

```
foreach (var i in List)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", i, ListDesc.FindIndex(a => a == i));
}
```

There's no need for `ListDesc` anyway. Just use `ListAsc`:

```
var OrderedListDesc  = List.OrderByDescending(b => ListAsc.FindIndex(a => a == b)).ToList();
```

Or, use `ListDesc` and call `OrderBy` rather than `OrderByDescending`:

```
var OrderedListDesc  = List.OrderBy(b => ListDesc.FindIndex(a => a == b)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice the problem is, when an element(value) not found `FindIndex` returns  `-1`, which will appear first in order. Assign the maximum value when element is not found.

```
    var OrderedListDesc  = List.OrderBy(b => 
                                {
                                    var index = ListDesc.FindIndex(a => a == b);
                                    return index==-1? int.MaxValue : index;
                                }).ToList();
```

A small tip (not relating to issue), if you want to print `,` separated values you could simply use `string.Join` as below.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", OrderedListDesc));
```

**Output:**

```
7 ,6 ,5 ,4 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,8 ,9 ,
```

Check this [`Fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xa83CV)